# Calling out tells

Tags: etiquette, tells

A friend of mine has a habit of pointing out others' tells to the group that we are playing with (eg, "John just moved his card like so--he definitely has at least a pair"). I argued that this is bad etiquette and akin to cheating. Others said that he is simply sharing strategy and that people do this "all the time" when playing card games. So the question is: Do you tell tells, or no?

Comment: IMO it's kind of stupid to do. If you're succesful at identifying and exploiting tells, why would you give up that advantage ? It's your levarage against the other players....

Comment: I think the _others_ are you referring to don't play live games very often :) Sure you want to tell tells, but the wrong ones :) Although no in the _Tony G_ way, shouting.

Answer (score 6):

It depends whether the hand was in progress or not. I think you are free to tell tells if you like, you will lose out though and will annoy people hoping to exploit this tell.

If this happened in the middle of a hand, however, it's different. In general it is considered bad etiquette and may even be against the rules to talk about the hand in progress. The "one player to a hand" rule means that a player must make a decision alone with no outside input. I think saying something like "you should call, he just gave a tell there" would be against this rule and should be penalised.

Comment: Yes, during the hand it is *very*, *very*, against the rules. Between hands, if you want to say "Bob has this tell...", it's a free country. But during the hand, if Bob makes a bet and you tell Fred "call him, he's bluffing", Bob is entitled to beat you senseless and no one would be the least bit sympathetic. Yes, it happens on TV all the time, just like string bets, but in real poker games, people have been shot for less.